# Cypress - Cucumber JUnit XML report

Tags: xml, junit, cucumber, report, cypress

I wish to create JUnit style XML reports from Cypress - Cucumber tests so that they can be used by Azure pipelines. Even XUnit report is fine.

Is there any detailed step to follow to achieve this?

I'm currently using [multiple-cucumber-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiple-cucumber-html-reporter).

Comment: I hope you can find a suitable report plugin [here](https://docs.cypress.io/plugins/index.html#reporting)

Comment: You can probably use [cytorus](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/cytorus) which generated reports in json format, if that can help you.

Comment: If you don't necessarily want or need to use the XML files, I can recommend the following extension for displaying the generated cucumber.json files for Azure Pipelines: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MaciejMaciejewski.azure-pipelines-cucumber